# async else / Angular is not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ionic3

I have a code as shown below. It is working fine on `ngIf` use case. But it has an issue with `else` use case. That is, it shows else part and suddenly vanished without any change of `observable`. In other words no change of the data. Can you tell me why? How to avoid it?

*This is the behavior of it now:*

[image]

*html*

```
 <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="budgetGroup" *ngIf="budgetGroups$ | async; let bg;else loading">
        <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let b of bg | orderByBudgetGroup">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>{{b.name }}</ion-label>
            <ion-radio [value]="b.id" (ionSelect)="selectedBudgetGroup(b)"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item-options side="right">
            <button ion-button (click)="editBudgetGroup(b)" color="primary">
              <ion-icon name="ios-create-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button ion-button (click)="deleteBudgetGroup(b)" color="danger">
              <ion-icon name="ios-trash-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-item-options>
        </ion-item-sliding>
        <ion-item>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

     <ng-template #loading>
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row class="header">
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row class="footer">
            <ion-col col-12 class="font-size-14" text-center>
              <div>
                <P class="margin-bottom-0">No Budget Group. You can create them by </P>
                <p class="margin-top-0">tapping the “+” button above</p>
              </div>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </ng-template>
```

*.ts*

```
budgetGroups$: Observable<BudgetGroup[]>;budgetGroup: string;

 ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.budgetGroups$ = this.budgetGroupProvider.getAllBudgetGroups().valueChanges();
 }
```

*service.ts*

```
  getAllBudgetGroups(): AngularFirestoreCollection<BudgetGroup> {
    return this.budgetGroupCollectionRef = this.fireStore.collection(`userProfile/${this.userId}/budgetGroup`);
  }
```

Comment: where is `[(ngModel)]="budgetGroup"` coming from? you will have to use async everywhere in template

Comment: Please see the update on `ts` file @SurajRao

Comment: It's possible to have the code of `getAllBudgetGroups`? I don't understand why you have a `.valueChanges` and not only `this.budgetGroups$ = this.budgetGroupProvider.getAllBudgetGroups()`

Comment: Please see the update @mickaelw

Answer (score 0):

`budgetGroups` would return a empty array even it's shown `[]`.`*ngIf` wouldn't detech empty array so that you need to check your return is blank or not.

**code**

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="budgetGroup" 
*ngIf="(budgetGroups$ | async)[0]; let bg;else loading">
```

Comment: It gives this error `SelectBudgetGroupPage.html:17 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SelectBudgetGroupPage.html:67)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14338)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13507)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13857)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:13789)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13513)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13857)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:13815)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13857)`